# PHP - Using a global variable inside a class (Fatal Error)

Tags: php, function, pdo

I have a `class.php` file, in which I include a class from another file:

class.php:

```
 include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/user.php");
 $user = new User;
```

So, inside `/includes/user.php` is the `$user` class defined.

And in `/includes/user.php` there is a function named `getSocialUser($username);`:

```
function getSocialUser ($username)
{
    global $dbh;
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    $udata = $stmt->fetch();

    if(count($udata) == 0)
        return false;

    return $udata;
}
```

(The `$dbh` holds the database value. I've tested it, and it does have a connection to the database)

However, I want to be able to use that function above inside the `class.php` file:

This is what I am doing now:

class.php:

```
 include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/user.php");
 $user = new User;  


 Class feed {

   function randomFunction($username) {
   global $user;
   $username = "test";
   $viewuser = $user->getSocialUser($username);

   echo $viewuser['avatar'];
  }
}
```

The above code doesn't work. I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSocialUser() on a non-object in/path/class.php on line 6
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your code was really exactly as you've depicted it, there would be no error.

Comment: @TomHoang: He already has that.

Comment: @Boann Well, there is.

Comment: @oliverbj Then the real code is different to the code in the question.

Comment: Are you sure that you are showing the correct code? `non-object in/path/class.php on line 6` and `->getSocialUser` is not on a line 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off, using GLOBAL is bad practice. Instead, add the database connection as a parameter, so change your function to the following

```
function getSocialUser ($dbh, $username)
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    $udata = $stmt->fetch();

    if(count($udata) == 0)
        return false;

    return $udata;
}
```

Next, initiate the database connection and the user class in a construct of your class,

```
 Class feed {
     private $dbh;
     private $user;

     function __construct() {
         $this->dbh = new PDO('your data here');
         $this->user = new User();
     }

     function randomFunction($username) {
         $username = "test";
         $viewuser = $this->user->getSocialUser($this->dbh,$username);
         echo $viewuser['avatar'];
     }
 }
```

Comment: What would be inside the __construct()?

Comment: Nothing. You don't need to supply any parameters for it. The construct is a magic function that will run whenever the class is called and it will initiate the two other classes you need, PDO and the user class so that you can use them in further methods (functions) and reference them as properties.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using GLOBALS, as they would bind your classes to a specific context and reduce the reusasbility and the cohesion of your software, among other issues that make GLOBALS bad design decisions. Instantiating the User ob jectinside the Feed constructor if also not recommended because is you have to change the User class constructor then you'll have to go back the to Feed class and change it also. Try to give your classes only one reason to change, that will improve cohesion.

Use dependency injection to improve your design:

For your user class you could pass the database handler as a parameter to the class constructor, this is called constructor injection:

```
/*file User.php*/

class User 
{
    private $dbh;

    public function __construct(PDO $dbh)
    {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }

    public function getSocialUser($username)
    {
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        $udata = $stmt->fetch();

        if (empty($udata) == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return $udata;
    }
}
```

For your feed class, you could use delegation and constructor injection or setter injection:

```
/* File Feed.php*/

require_once 'User.php';

Class Feed
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    function randomFunction($username) {

        $viewuser = $this->user->getSocialUser($username);

        return $viewuser['avatar'];
    }
}
```

Now you can use:

```
/* file foobar.php */

require_once 'User.php';
require_once 'Feed.php';

// Create your PDO - $dbh

$user = new User($dbh);
$feed = new Feed($user);

$testName = 'test';

echo $feed->randomFunction($testName);
```

I've tried to keep the code simple, so I've skipped error checking. I hope this can help you solve your problem. Here is some info on dependency injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection